# What's the difference between an ergodic measure, ergodic sequence or ergodic mapping?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-walk, ergodic-theory

So I work a lot with ergodic theorems but it is a bit confusing.
We have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\}$ and a measure preserving mapping $T:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega$.
We say that $T$ is ergodic (or $P$-ergodic) if any event in the $T$-invariant $\sigma$-algebra has probability $1$ or $0$. This is not entirely clear to me.
As example consider a simple random walk in a random environment, with $\{\omega_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\omega_i$ the probability to jump to the right at position $i$.
Now how do I show that this sequence is ergodic? There is no mapping $T$ involved.

Comment: In your case $\Omega$ is a space of sequences, and $T$ is the shift, sending sequence $(\omega_i)$ to sequence $(\omega_{i+1})$ (or maybe it's $\omega_{i-1}$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notions of ergodic measure and ergodic mapping are more or less interchangeable. If you already have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}),$ you would say that a measure-preserving transformation $T: X \rightarrow X$ is ergodic if $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0, 1\}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ for which $T^{-1}(A) = A$ (this is one of many equivalent definitions). You could also say in this scenario that $\mathbb{P}$ is ergodic (with respect to $T$). However, there are situations in which you are only given a mapping $T$ and are asked if there exists an ergodic measure with respect to $T$ (a very well known theorem shows that if $X$ is a complete metric space and $T$ is continuous, then indeed there exists an ergodic measure). So it really depends on the context, really. As for ergodic sequences, I believe that the [wikipedia page on ergodic sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_sequence) is a good reference. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. So now I understand the notions of ergodic measure and mapping. But what if $X:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega$ is a sequence (say random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$. We have $T$ that maps $X_t$ to $X_{t+1}$. Then I would like to now whether this RW is ergodic. Is it possible that my $\mathbb{P}$ is ergodic and thus any sequence which follows the law of this measure? Because, normally the RW on $\mathbb{Z}$ is not ergodic. So I want to know the link between ergodic mapping/measure and ergodic sequence. The wiki page won't help in this case. Thanks already, I really appreciate it.